# "makes pointer from integer without a cast" when outputting a pointer to a text file

Tags: c, pointers, casting, printf

Sorry for being a noob but I just don't understand what's wrong here.

I'm trying to make a function to write to a text file with a pointer to a string as the input. The function is outstring(); where it's input is the string I want put on the txt file.

In main() I can do:

```
printf("the string is: %s\n", charcall(stringoutptr));
```

but I can't do:

```
outstring(charcall(stringoutptr));
```

Here is the error bellow when I compile:

```
mynamehere (~): gcc csvtest.c -o csvtest
csvtest.c: In function 'outstring':
csvtest.c:24:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    fprintf(ptr_file, outstringinput);
    ^
In file included from csvtest.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:356:12: note: expected 'const char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char'
extern int fprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
           ^
```

My source-code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static const char outfile[] = "LETS SEE IF THIS WORKS"; // just some sample string

int charcall(instring) // a function to return the value of the pointer
{
    return instring;
}


int outstring(outstringinput)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int x;

    ptr_file =fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    for (x=1; x<=12; x++)
    fprintf(ptr_file,"%d\n", x);

    fprintf(ptr_file, outstringinput);

    fclose(ptr_file);
}

int main()
{
    char stringoutput[50] = "somestring in main\n";
    char *stringoutptr;
    stringoutptr = stringoutput;

    // bellow = line 39
    outstring(charcall(stringoutptr)); // I'm trying to output "some strhing in main" onto the text file
    // bellow = line 40
    printf("the string is: %s\n", charcall(stringoutptr)); // this works and prints the string "some string in main"

    // why does line 39 work and 40 not? 

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: This code can't be for real, arguments do not even have their types mentioned.

Comment: `int charcall(instring)` --> `char *charcall(char *instring)`, `int outstring(outstringinput)` --> `void outstring(char *outstringinput)`

Comment: or`int outstring(char *outstringinput)` and `fclose(ptr_file);return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your code with appropriate types added to allow it to do what you want it to do. Your function return types must match the way you are going to use the returns in your code. (i.e. if you want to use `charcall` to return a character pointer to a string, then it must be declared as `char *charcall`) Look through the example below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static const char outfile[] = "LETS SEE IF THIS WORKS";

char *charcall (char *instring)
{
    return instring;
}


int outstring (char *outstringinput)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int x;

    ptr_file = fopen ("output.txt", "w");

    if (!ptr_file)
        return 0;

    for (x=1; x<=12; x++)
        fprintf (ptr_file, "%d\n", x);

    fprintf (ptr_file, "%s\n", outstringinput); /* pass outstringinput as a char* (not as format with 0 shift) */

    fclose (ptr_file);

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char stringoutput[50] = "somestring in main\n";
    char *stringoutptr;
    stringoutptr = stringoutput;

    outstring (charcall (stringoutptr));

    printf ("the string is: %s\n", charcall (stringoutptr));

    return 0;
}
```

**build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/ostr outstring.c
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/ostr
the string is: somestring in main

$ cat output.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
somestring in main
```